# How to send and receive messages

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, server

I'm working on a messaging app. To send messages from one app to another phone's app do I need something like firebase? Is it not possible to directly send packages from one phone to another?

I've been looking into firebase. And there's a tutorial I'm following, but I'm still confused.

Comment: Yes, you will need some server/database. You can't send directly.

Comment: Firebase is a great solution for this task and provided a wide variety of services to support it - including authentication, database and storage. However, the question is off topic for SO as this site is for coding specific questions.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need Firebase to build a messaging app. You can just use websocket for send and receive messages. Firebase is a **realtime** database. Firebase using **websocket** for data synchronization with clients.  If you want to dive deep into **realtime** technology, use websocket. If you want to build a messaging app quickly, use firebase.